# How to toggle WiFi hotspot programmatically in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-wifi, hotspot

Why does this code not work in Android 5.0?

What methods I should call to turn it On/Off in Android 5.0?

```
WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
wificonfiguration.SSID = "Wifi Hotspot";

wificonfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
wificonfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wificonfiguration.preSharedKey = "123";
WifiManager mWifiManager;
mWifiManager = (WifiManager) this.context1.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


try {
  if (mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) { // disable WiFi in any case
    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
  }

  Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);

  method.invoke(mWifiManager, wificonfiguration, true);




  //Toast.makeText(context, "OK", 0).show();

} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e);
}
```

Add in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: logs? any exception?

Comment: On side note in WPA, password must of at least 8 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch specific exceptions to know what went wrong more clearly . 
Try this -

```
private boolean setWifiApEnabled()
    {
        boolean result = false;
        // initialise you wifiManager first 
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        Method enableWifi;
        try {
            enableWifi = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Logger.e(TAG,e.toString());
            return result;
        }

        WifiConfiguration  myConfig =  new WifiConfiguration();
        myConfig.SSID = "Your SSID";
        myConfig.preSharedKey  = "Your pass";
        myConfig.status =   WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        myConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        myConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        myConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        myConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP); 
        myConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP); 
        myConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
        myConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        try {
            result = (Boolean) enableWifi.invoke(wifiManager, myConfig,status);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            Logger.e(TAG,e.toString());
            return result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Which device are you trying on ?
Have you tried multiple devices ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception ???
Try add android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS  in manifest and then check